# How to change the ringer mode in xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

Im trying to change the ringer mode to silent on a button click using AudioManager in Xamarin.forms android project

i tried this code and i actually think it is the right one

```
private void Silent_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AudioManager am = (AudioManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
            am.RingerMode = RingerMode.Silent;
        }
```

but im getting this error about the GetSystemService

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'MainPage' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetSystemService' and no accessible extension method
>   'GetSystemService' accepting a first argument of type 'MainPage' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   RingDemo    C:\Users\GTS\Desktop\RingDemo\RingDemo\RingDemo\MainPage.xaml.cs    25  Active

i cant figure out the right assembly for it

Comment: you are trying to use Android code in your common Forms project.  That won't work.  You need to use a XF DependencyService to do this

Comment: @Jason is there a simple doc for this?

Comment: first hit in Google - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Xamarin.forms` project, define a interface:

```
public interface IChangeRingModeService
{
    void changeRingMode();
}
```

In your `.Android` project, create a new class and implement that interface:

```
public class ChangeRingModeService : IChangeRingModeService
{
    public void changeRingMode()
    {
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
        am.RingerMode = RingerMode.Silent;
    }
}
```

In you click event, call the `changeRingMode`:

```
private void Silent_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DependencyService.Get<IChangeRingModeService>().changeRingMode();
}
```

Comment: im getting this exception:
Unhandled Exception:

System.NullReferenceException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details> occurred

Comment: No worries, fixed it by registering the dependency. Thanks alot!